# How to get the "difference" between two objects in another object with the same structure using powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, data-structures

TL;DR: [This but in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)
I'm trying to get the "difference" between a list1 and a list2 where list2 is just a sub-set of list1. (or list1 is a super-set of list2).

Keep in mind that this is not the 'real scenario' but the structures of both objects are the same as this:

```
#List of all the IDs
$list1='2','5','6','11'
$CustObject1=foreach($i in $list1){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        id=$i
    }
}
#Another list, where invalid IDs are not listed
$list2='2','5'
$CustObject2=foreach($i in $list2){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        id=$i
    }
}
#I am looking for $CustObject3 = {id = '6',id = '11'}
```

Now, I want to create a new "object" that contains a list of **all** the 'invalid' IDs, in our example the `$CustObject3` would contain just id's `'6','11'`.
The reason behind this is because I have a list of 3000 ids that are "valid" and just a couple that are "invalid" (at most 10).
I've tried a lot of options but I can't get it to work, used "where", used double foreach loops, honestly I'm just frustrated at this point but I did try to make it work.

Is this feasible?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CustObject1.ID -DifferenceObject $CustObject2.ID).InputObject`.

Comment: Sadly that does not maintain the NoteProperty "id" that's needed for another process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-notin` or `-notcontains` operators to perform the check.

```
#List of all the IDs
$list1='2','5','6','11'
$CustObject1=foreach($i in $list){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        id=$i
    }
}
#Another list, where invalid IDs are not listed
$list2='2','5'
$CustObject2=foreach($i in $list){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        id=$i
    }
}

$CustObject1 | Where-Object {$_.id -notin $CustObject2.id}
```

Comment: The issue is that you used `$Custom..` instead of just `$Cust` lol small typo

Answer (score 1):

Unpack the ids from the PSCustomObjects, put them in HashSets, and then do ExceptWith():

```
$Ids      = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]]$CustObject1.id)
$validIds = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]]$CustObject2.id)

$Ids.ExceptWith($validIds)
```

Here `$Ids` starts with all the Ids, then removes the valid ones. It's updated internally and ends with only the invalid ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the other one is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) cmdlet:

```bash
$CustObject3 = 
  Compare-Object -Property id -PassThru $CustObject1 $CustObject2 | 
  Select-Object * -Exclude SideIndicator
```

Note:

- `Compare-Object` decorates the passed-through objects with a `.SideIndicator` property indicating which of the input collections a given object is unique to (`<=` for objects unique to the first collection, `=>` for those unique to the second).
- Since this information is not of interest here (all result objects are by definition unique to the first collection), `Select-Object * -Exclude SideIndicator` then removes this extra property.